# "dir" fail to find all files when there is a file with long name in R

Tags: r

I tried to get a file list in a focal directory by using `dir` function on Windows 11, but I found that it fails to get all files without any error/warning in some cases. Upon my further investigation (see the following code in detail), `dir` fail to get all files when there is a file whose name is very long (apparently more than 259 bytes). `dir` seems to stop the further search when they reach to the file with very long name, and so the other files listed on after that file are also not found even if their names are short. Interestingly, even when `dir` fail to detect the file with very long name, `file.exists` still detects its existence correctly.

---

##### ADD 2023.08.30 12:44 UTC

I tried the following code in **R 4.3.1** on Windows 11. It causes **crash** in **R 4.2.2**.

---

```
#create test directory
dir.create("test",showWarnings = FALSE)

# step 0 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#generate 01_test.txt, 02_test.txt, ...
for(i in c(1,2,3,11,12,13)){
    file.create(sprintf("test/%02d_test.txt",i))
}
# dir find all six files.
dir("test")

# step 1 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# use unicode character
#   on windws, file names are coded in UTF8 (?) 
#   \3042 is a Japanese kana character.
longname = paste(c("test/05_test",rep("\u3042",times=10),".txt"),collapse = "")
file.create(longname)

# Again, dir find all (now seven) files.
dir("test")

# step 2 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# try longer file name
# in UTF8, u3042 is 3 bytes, so "05_test"(7 bytes)+ 83*3bytes + ".txt" 4bytes = 260 bytes
morelongname = paste(c("test/05_test",rep("\u3042",times=83),".txt"),collapse = "")
file.create(morelongname)

# dir fail to find all (now eight) files.
#   dir seems to stop searching files which appear after the "morelongname" file, 
#   i.e., 11_test.txt, 12_test.txt, 13_test.txt are also not not found. 
dir("test",full.names = TRUE)

# however, file.exists can detect the existence. 
file.exists(morelongname)

# file.remove also works well 
file.remove(morelongname)

# step 3 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# try one-byte shoter name
# "05_tes"(6 bytes)+ 83*3bytes + ".txt" 4bytes = 259 bytes
morelongname2 = paste(c("test/05_tes",rep("\u3042",times=83),".txt"),collapse = "")
file.create(morelongname2)

# works well, so 260 bytes seems to be the border.
dir("test",full.names = TRUE)
```

I know that Windows limits file names to 260 characters, but it should only be the number of characters and not the number of bytes.

My question is

1. Is this expected normal behavior of `dir`? Or is it a bug?
2. It is difficult to identify in advance from R that there is a file with a long name in the folder. It is also difficult to discover that it has failed because it gives no error or warning. If the file name is extremely long. Do you have any idea how to detect/avoid this problem? In my case, it is okay to ignore the file with very long name because it is very rare cases.

---

##### ADD 2023.08.31 01:51 UTC

I tried two solutions.

One is the use of `system` function with intern option; which return the output of command as character.

```
system("dir test",intern=TRUE) |> 
    stringr::str_split("\\s+") |> 
    purrr::flatten_chr()
```

It works partially, but fail to read unicode characters.

```
[1] "01_test.txt"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[2] "02_test.txt"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[3] "03_test.txt"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[4] "05_test\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202.txt"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[5] "05_test\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201\\202\\343\\201"
[6] "11_test.txt"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[7] "12_test.txt"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[8] "13_test.txt"
```

\343\201\202 is UTF8 three codes of \u3042, so I guess this is the problem of encode, but anyway I could not solved this.

---

The other is suggested by @Jean-Claude Arbaut in the comment; the call of python from reticulate package.

```
os = reticulate::import("os")
os$listdir("test")
```

Although there is small overhead when we import os module, **it works well!** At least in my case, this method is likely solution.

Comment: It may be worth reading Tomas Kalibera's recent blog post: https://blog.r-project.org/2023/03/07/path-length-limit-on-windows/

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you for the comments. About the file name code, I misunderstood. However, I checked the relationship between the number of Unicode character and ASCII characters, so I guess this problem seems to caused in UTF-8; at least the Unicode character \u3042 is counted as 3 bytes.

About the crash, even in my environment crash occurs in R4.2.2, but it works without error in R4.3.1. I added this information in the post.

Comment: @MikaelJagan, thank you for the information. From your comment, I found a release news about [changes in R4.3.0](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.pdf), "R on Windows is now able to work with path names longer than 260 characters when these are enabled in the system (requires at least Windows 10 version 1607)." So, the reason why the crash not occur in R4.3.1 may be related to this! However, they are saying about the character number instead of byte number, and my total path length is less than 260, so I think my code should be supported even before this release...

Comment: My own view is: if you're using file names of that kind of length, you need to rethink your naming convention.  I had big enough problems accessing remote (inside-company)servers due to the absurdly long directory paths thanks to Windows' stupid limits on path lengths.   Don't make it worse

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  My comment, referring to long file names, is IMHO still valid, because ridiculously long names start to lose their meaning, or at least make it really difficult to find the specific file wanted.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I perfectly agree with the opinion that the too long names are not only worthless but harmful. However, in my case, these problematic files come from outside. It is difficult to prevent the submission of a file with too long name, and once such a file mix in my folder, other files with enough short names also not be found by `dir`...

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you for the suggestion. It works well! I updated my post with your solution!